# Use of ! operator in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

`_formKey.currentState!.validate()`

`currentState` is a `State`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html

So, what is the use of `!` after `currentState`?
`!` is used in front of boolean variables but `State` is not a boolean.

Please explain what is happening here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `!` is called the postfix null assertion “bang” operator. The property [`currentState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey/currentState.html) is of type `T?`, which means it can be null. Therefore if you do:

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
_formKey.currentState.validate();
```

You will get the following error:

> The method 'validate' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
> Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

To solve it, you can use the postfix null operator:

```
_formKey.currentState!.validate();
```

The postfix exclamation mark (!) takes the expression on the left and casts it to its underlying non-nullable type. So the above is the same as doing:

```
(_formKey.currentState as FormState).validate();
```

Check the docs for more info:

https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#null-assertion-operator